# Can not connect HTC Vive headset - Steam VR plugin error Failed to load IVRRenderModels

Tags: unity, camera, steam, htc-vive

When I add SteamVR plugin I receive error
Failed to load IVRRenderModels interface version IVRRenderModels_005.

The plugin works for my other projects, camera and controllers are detected and work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I did a few things:

First was to try [this answer](https://answers.unity.com/answers/1362612/view.html).

Editing the settings file worked OK. It removed the error message and kicked Steam to stay open, but my cameraRig was still not connecting to the headset in the imported scene and in the project it was coming from.

In the end I copied a camera object tree from working scene - one combining VRTK + steamVR cameraRig and it connected

Reconstructing camera object in Other scenes with problems works again too.

In the meantime I updated Viveport, changed back and forth usb ports, rebooted headset, restarted pc, removed and re-imported SteamVR plugin and VRTK and many others.

Hope my experience helps someone else too.